# In CakePHP, how can I allow access to a number of pages while using auth?

Tags: cakephp

I currently have a log in system implemented that works fine. However, I can't access any other pages of the website without it telling me to log in. I just want one page to be hidden behind the login function. (Obviously the user will be able to be logged in while accessing other areas of the site as well)

For example, I want to access /view/home/index.ctp so I tried:

```
$this->Auth->allow(array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
```

But this does not allow access to the home page, and I am stuck on the login page which the site defaults to.

Would anybody mind helping me with this?

Using CakePHP 2.4.6 if that matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a 'beforeFilter' function that will allow you to define certain functions within your Controller which don't require Authorization.  For example, in the 'Users' controller (or 'home' controller, which it sounds like you're using):

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('logout', 'login', 'index'); //you can add others here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to do the auth->allow in my appcontroller for some reason. x_x